# Can you point out what is wrong with this thought experiment?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Relativity claims that the simultaneity between two (or more) observers, each traveling in different Inertial Reference Frames (IRFs) is such that “Both observers consider the clock of the other as running slower”. This is shown on a Minkowski diagram in the section titled “Time dilation” on the Wikipedia page for “Minkowski diagram”. However, as I will explain, this interpretation leads to an inconsistency which cannot be true. I point out the error being made in the interpretation of Minkowski diagrams that leads to this inconsistency, and how the diagram should be interpreted to correct this error.

**Can you confirm this analysis, or otherwise point out a valid flaw in the argument put forward?**

Marco Ocram replied on a different message thread that has since been deleted suggesting that he has an explanation as to why he thinks the analysis is wrong...

**Here is the reasoning:**

The first diagram above is a Minkowski diagram depicting two spaceships approaching each other at 40% of the speed of light. Ship A is moving from left to right and ship B from right to left.   The Black axes are for a stationary observer between ships A and B (y axis is ct, x axis is distance). The Green axes are ct’ and ct’’ respectively and the blue axes are x’ and x’’ respectively.

The dashed blue lines are parallel to x’ and x’’ and are lines of simultaneity for each of the ships (A and B). These dashed lines pass through an event on the stationary observer’s ct axis (at coordinates 0,50), where the event is indicated by a blue dot.

The second diagram shows two light signals (in Cyan). One from Ship A to the stationary observer at coordinate (0,50), and another from the stationary observer to Ship A. Also shown in Red is the correction made by each observer to the time of the received light signal, such that he can determine when the signal was sent.

The third diagram shows the light signal from Ship A continuing on to reach Ship B after passing the stationary observer (dashed cyan line). Then on Ship B's ct axis he applies his time correction for the entire travel time of the light signal (the time to go from Ship A to the stationary observer, plus the time to go on from there to Ship B's ct axis). As you can see, the observer on Ship B determines that the time on Ship A is the same as his own.

The fourth diagram shows the same information as the third diagram, but re-drawn from the point of view of Ship A (Ship A's Inertial Reference Frame).

For the details on how such time corrections to received light signals should be made, please see the section at the end of this question titled 'APPLYING THE TIME CORRECTION TO RECEIVED LIGHT SIGNALS'.

According to relativity, where the lines of simultaneity of ships A and B pass through the other ships ct axis (indicated by Black dots) indicates what the time on the other ship (B and A respectively) is. Therefore, so Relativity claims, ship A observes a different time on ship B, and vice-versa. However, it is easy to prove that this interpretation is wrong: If each of the three observers (ship A, ship B and the stationary observer in the middle) send signals to each other indicating their own current time, then each of the signals from ship A and ship B arrive at the event on the stationary observer’s ct axis (indicated by a blue dot).

Simultaneously, the stationary observer’s time signal travels from the blue dot to each of ships A and B ct axes (indicated by the Red dots). As all three of these points are connected by lines of simultaneity, all readings correspond to the same moment (although each observers clock may show a different time). Each ship sends its current time to the observer at the Blue dot and he displays the times on a screen visible to each ship, each ship sees the screen at a time simultaneous with its Red dot. So, as the Red dot points are simultaneous with the blue dot event on the stationary observer’s ct axis, the Black dot points CANNOT also be simultaneous with these events as Relativity claims.

So, to correctly determine the time that is simultaneous on ship A from ship B’s point of view (and vice-versa), one must follow the dashed blue line of simultaneity from ship B up to the point where it intersects with ship A’s line of simultaneity (the other dashed Blue line) - one could draw a stationary IRF (drawn on the diagram as orthogonal x and ct axes) at this point. Then one must follow ship A’s line of simultaneity until it intersects with ship A’s ct axis.

This misunderstanding about the Relativity of simultaneity is due to the failure to recognize that each ship’s axes represents a different coordinate system and one must map from one coordinate system to the other coordinate system when drawing inferences between the two systems.

```
                           ------------------------
```

**PROOF THAT SHIP A & B TIMES ARE AT THE SAME RATE
USING THE LORENTZ TRANSFORMATIONS:**

That Ship A and B have the same rate of time is easily proved:

Transforming each ship to the IRF of the central observer, then eliminating the central IRF by substituting one LT into the other:

```
  Note:

  For single primed '  :   v is positive, Δx is negative

  For double primed '' :   v is negative, Δx is positive
```

For Time:

Δt'  = γ[Δt + v/c² Δx]

Δt'' = γ[Δt + v/c² Δx]

Δt = Δt''/γ - v/c² Δx

Δt' = γ[(Δt''/γ - v/c² Δx) + v/c² Δx]

Δt' = γ[Δt''/γ]

Δt' = Δt''

For Space:

Δx'  = γ(-Δx - v Δt)

Δx'' = γ(Δx + v Δt)

Δx = Δx''/γ - v Δt

Δx' = γ(-(Δx''/γ - v Δt) - v Δt)

Δx' = -γ(Δx''/γ)

Δx' = -Δx''

(which we know to be true, as each ship is equidistant on either side of the origin)

```
                           ------------------------
```

**APPLYING THE TIME CORRECTION TO RECEIVED LIGHT SIGNALS**

For each Ship, from the moment he receives a signal from the other ship, or stationary observer, he must apply a time correction on his ct axis in order to know what his own time was when the signal was sent. As the Minkowski diagram is drawn from the point of view of the stationary observer, he must take his own motion into consideration in order to apply the correction properly. First, he must determine the travel time of the light signal (as determined from the Minkowski diagram using the stationary observer’s axes).

As the light signal travels at 45 degrees in any IRF on a Minkowski diagram, he simply traces the light path back in time until it intersects the known trajectory of Ship A. This point must then indicate where and when the light signal was emitted. Then he must determine the distance on the Minkowski diagram (drawn from the stationary observer’s perspective) to trace back along his ct axis. This can be done by multiplying the time interval dt by the length along his ct axis corresponding to one unit of time on the stationary observer’s ct axis (hB, the length of the hypotenuse of a triangle with side lengths of 1 and β).

To determine his actual time at the moment the light signal was emitted, he must divide the distance along his ct axis (just determined) by the unit time length on his ct axis (given by U). For moving inertial reference frames, U will be greater than 1. Once this is done, he must subtract this result from his measured light arrival time in order to know what his own time was when the light was emitted.

The time correction to determine Ship B’s time is:

```
∆t = -(hB∙dt)/UB = -dt/γ
```

Where:

```
dt is the travel time of the light signal (using the stationary observer’s axes).

B   refers to values for the observer of the light signal.

hB  refers to the length of the hypotenuse of a triangle with side lengths of 1 and β.


β = v/c 

hB = √(1+β^2)

γ = 1/√(1-β^2) 

U = hB∙γ = √((1+β^2)/(1-β^2))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100658/discussion-on-question-by-declan-traill-can-you-point-out-what-is-wrong-with-thi).

Comment: Why has my question been put on hold (again)?  It is clearly relevant in at least two areas outlined by the Help Center as acceptable:

(1) Explanations of observed physical or astronomical phenomena
(2) Mathematics in the context of physics

Comment: @DeclanTraill It also falls into an explicit off topic area - [check my work](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6097/127931) questions.  Asking people to point out what is wrong is generally off-topic, especially when the motivation seems to be an explicit attempt to disprove mainstream science than an actual question about the underlying concepts.

Comment: I think it deserves to be off topic based on how you have received the answers here. It's obvious that you aren't actually asking for people to show you what is wrong with your thoughts here. You think you are right and you will not consider what someone has to say if they don't think you are right also. Therefore, it is unclear at to what you are really asking for here

Comment: @AaronStevens That is an unfair characterization. I am explaining the situation from a different set of assumptions, which are also completely consistent with the known empirical facts. There is insufficient experimental evidence for this sort of thought experiment for anyone to be able to claim they are definitely right - even for mainstream science. I asking people to think about the traditional way of analyzing this situation and am pointing out that there are inconsistencies in that approach which can be removed by using this alternate set of valid assumptions.

Comment: Hi, we've noticed that you have made a large number of minor edits to this post. Please be mindful that every edit bumps the post in the "active" tab of the site and try to make your edits substantial. If you foresee improving this post repeatedly, maybe collect several edits and make them in one go instead of submitting them individually.

Answer (score 3):

Declan,

What is right about your thought experiment is that the blue dot is simultaneous with the left hand red dot in the frame of ship A and with the right hand red-dot in the frame of ship B.

Everything else is wrong.

The dashed blue line through the left hand red dot is a line of constant time in the frame moving with spaceship A. So if it is 4.07 on Spaceship A then it is 4.07 anywhere along that line for anyone moving with the same velocity as spaceship A.

Likewise, the dashed blue line through the right hand red dot is a line of constant time in the frame moving with spaceship B. So if it is also 4.07 on spaceship B then it is also 4.07 anywhere along that line for anyone moving with the same velocity as spaceship B.

The only place in all of spacetime at which it is 4.07 in both reference frames simultaneously is the point where the two dashed blue lines meet. Everywhere else there is a disagreement. Take the right hand black dot. In the frame of spaceship A it is 4.07 at the right hand black dot. Clearly the right hand black dot is much later than 4.07 in the frame of spaceship B.

Comment: Marco, so you agree "that the blue dot is simultaneous with the left hand red dot in the frame of ship A and with the right hand red-dot in the frame of ship B". So, if Ship B sends it's current time (4.07) to the Blue dot at coordinate (0,50), and then that signal is continues from the Blue dot on to Ship A, the light signal will follow the cyan line in the 2nd diagram and reach Ship A's ct axis. The observer on Ship A then applies the time correction for a signal coming from the Blue dot location (shown as the Red line down Ship A's ct axis). This reveals both Ship's times to be identical.

Comment: The Relativity of Simultaneity is usually described as each Ship observing the other Ship's time to be running at a different rate, indicated by the other Ship's time at the Black dot locations. This is clearly not the case, and cannot be so, as the red dots are already simultaneous with each other, and only one time on each ct axis can be simultaneous with the other ct axis.

Comment: Declan, you are missing the point entirely. The relativity of simultaneity refers to the fact that the set of events that are simultaneous in one reference frame will not be simultaneous in another reference frame moving with respect to it. All of the points along the dashed line through ship A are simultaneous in shape A's reference frame. That's what the dashed line means. Do you not agree with that?

Comment: Marco, yes I agree that the dashed lines show which events are simultaneous for an observer. What I am objecting to is the assertion that each Ship observer sees the other Ship's time as running slowly. If he makes the time corrections then he will see that both Ship's times are running at the same rate.

Please see the section titled "Time Dilation" (two links), where they state that "Both observers consider the clock of the other as running slower":

[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_diagram)

[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Minkowski_diagram_-_time_dilation.svg)

Comment: Great. I'm just trying to pinpoint what you do and don't agree with. So if you agree that the dashed lines show events that are simultaneous for an observer, then  presumably you agree that for an observer in ship A, ship B's position is an event in the past? And likewise for an observer in ship B, ship A's position is an event in the past?

Comment: No. The dashed lines show events that are simultaneous for the ship in the stationary observers reference frame - that is how the moving observer's coordinate system was developed - but NOT in the coordinate system of another different moving observer. To do that is like having graph paper with both Cartesian grid line and logarithmic grid lines superimposed, and then making a reading of a logarithmic point on the graph using the Cartesian grid lines. They are two different coordinate systems! One must map from one to the other if you want to make a sensible reading.

Comment: This can be done by mapping form Ship A's point onto a stationary frame, and then mapping from the stationary frame to Ship B's coordinate system, using its axes.

Comment: Hi Declan. Many thanks. I think we've hit the buffers. You are either just plain wrong or we are all talking at cross-purposes in some way I can't pinpoint. I will have one last stab via an edit to my question later today. Don't give up.

Comment: Hi Declan. One quick clarification. In the question, do you assume the speed of light appears the same in all three reference frames, or are you assuming that light is moving at a certain speed in relation to a background energy field, as you have proposed in one of your other papers?

Comment: Yes, it is completely consistent with the known facts to have light traveling at c wrt a background energy field (determined by all the masses in the Universe), yet all observers in any IRF will still measure light's speed to be c for themselves. It must be this way, otherwise the actual path that the light travels through space will be different depending on which IRF point of view you take. That would mean that there is no objective reality.

Answer (score 2):

> Also shown in Red is the correction made by each observer to the time of the received light signal, such that he can determine when the signal was sent.

The method of correcting the time is actually the only thing that is important in determining simultaneity. You are not doing that correctly or consistently here in your example.

For an inertial observer to determine the time that a distant event occurred they send a light Pulse at $t_P$ (on their clock), that light pulse arrives at the event in Question at $t_Q$, and then the reflected signal is Received at $t_R$. Then, since the speed of light is isotropic that means that $t_Q$ is halfway in between $t_P$ and $t_R$, so $t_Q=\frac{1}{2}(t_P+t_R)$. Sometimes this method is called "radar time", but it follows directly from the fact that light always travels at c in an inertial frame.

[image: Diagram Showing Time Correction]

In the image above I have removed the lines of simultaneity for clarity and added three radar pulses, one for the blue event, one for the black event, and one for the red event. For each radar pulse I have labeled $t_P$ for the time that the pulse was emitted and $t_R$ for the time that the reflection is received. Then the time in question $t_Q$ is halfway between the two. According to the inertial observer sending the radar pulse, that time at the event in question, $t_Q$, is the same as the time exactly halfway between $t_P$ and $t_R$ on the observer's worldline. This is simultaneity.

As you can see above, the black and blue events are simultaneous for the primed observer because they have the same moment which is halfway between their respective $t_P$ and $t_R$. In contrast, the red event has a $t_Q$ which is much earlier than the black and blue events. The red event is not simultaneous with the other events.

There is no freedom to follow different lines of simultaneity as you suggest. Any other formula for calculating the time $t_Q$ will lead to an incorrect value of c.

Comment: That is incorrect. The two ships are moving towards each other at high speed so the time for the signal to travel from tP to tQ will be greater that the time from tQ to tR as the ships will have moved a considerable distance during the signal propagation time, so tQ is not "the time exactly halfway between tP and tR on the observer's worldline". You can clearly see that the times are different by looking at your diagram.

Comment: In any case, we are talking about what the rate of time is observed to be on the other ship - if the second ship's time was imprinted on the signal at tQ such that when it returned to tR the first ship can see what time it was, then he would have to apply the time correction to account for the signal's travel time from tP to tQ. When he does that he gets the same time as he had at tP - so the two ship's clocks agree with one another.

Comment: @Marco Ocram as predicted! A full on rejection of a correct answer, and definitely leaning more towards me being stupid rather than gullible. I do not call that “in good faith”

Comment: @Declan Traill you said “The two ships are moving towards each other at high speed so the time for the signal to travel from tP to tQ will be greater that the time from tQ to tR as the ships will have moved” but in the primed frame the primed observer is not moving and so the time in that frame is equal. That is the whole point. In the unprimed frame of the diagram he is moving so the times are unequal, but in the primed frame he is not moving so the times are equal.

Comment: I see why you think that, because light is always measured to be traveling at c in any inertial reference frame. But the problem is, depending on which reference frame you say is stationary, the real light signal would follow a different path through space. The actual path of the signal must be the same from any point of view. This can only be achieved if light propagates at c with respect to the space vacuum, and it is still possible for any observer to measure the speed of light to be c. The Michelson Morley result is also explained this way.

Comment: I have proved this in other work. [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228368645_Relatively_Simple_An_Introduction_to_Energy_Field_Theory)

Comment: You said “light is always measured to be traveling at c in any inertial reference frame”. That is all you need. Apply that rule consistently and you get the relativistic simultaneity. You just don’t apply it consistently. Oh well, as I predicted, you are not asking in good faith trying to learn. Your mind is already made up that I am stupid and maybe gullible (although I am getting more of an impression you think I’m stupid than gullible). It isn’t my job to convince you. I answered your question, that is the purpose of the site. I won’t argue further.

Comment: Why take it so personally - I'm not saying any of those things of you - I am simply explaining a different way to interpret and explain the situation in the thought experiment that is also consistent with empirical facts, such as the constancy of the speed of light. Can't you see that if light travels at c through space relative to each different IRF then it will follow a different path depending on each and every view point?  If, however, it travels wrt the space vacuum, then the path is the same for every observer, yet every observer will still measure its speed to be c.